# LOGCAT showing this error while running my app

Tags: java, android

LOGCAT error prevents me from opening the MAP activity and stops
working.

```
2019-07-03 17:12:01.642 29273-29273/com.example.ess E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ess, PID: 29273
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method map(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imageView5'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6993)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26512)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applied the `android:onClick=map` attribute in your layout xml.
As you can see in the log it's on the ImageView `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` with the `android:id=@+id/imageView5`

So either:

- remove this line: `android:onClick="map"` and handle clicks with an `OnClickListener`
- create this method in the Activity where you applied the layout:

```
public void map(View v) {}
```